# Is there any sound enhancer/equalizer for Linuxes that are not Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, rhel, audio, gentoo, pulseaudio

I am looking for a systemwide audio equalizer for Debian, Gentoo or Red Hat Enterprise Linux, i.e. an audio equalizer that filters the entire signal that is sent to the audio chipset, something functionally similar to the Windows Realtek AC97 audio driver's equalizer in order to be able to apply my sound tweaks to, say, Soundcloud tracks or Youtube videos.

Unfortunately, so far all I've found has been [a Pulseaudio hack for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer) that requires adding Ubuntu Launchpad repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I use Debian Jessie and Gentoo on my personal computer and RHEL 6.6 on my work computer. What can I do in this case?

Comment: I think http://jackaudio.org/applications/ provides what you want. It can incorporate "software effect processors" into the audio chain.

Comment: On Gentoo I use PulseAudio's built-in equalizer. Any further info can be found here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PulseAudio#Equalizer